# Rates of Keto-Enol Tautomerism

Tags: kinetics, reference-request, tautomer

Are there any databases with rate constants for keto-enol tautomerism in small molecules? I'm looking for rate constants if possible.

Comment: They're equilibrium processes so a rate constant isn't really meaningful

Comment: I'm asking if there is some kind of reference where I could obtain kinetic data of this type.  It is useful for what I am trying to do.

Comment: My point is that almost any carbonyl will exist to some extent in its enol form. You can't really measure a rate because no sooner as it's made, it's equilibrated. It's not a chemical reaction that you can 'start' and then 'quench' once it's done. Perhaps you can [edit] your post with more details/an example of what you're looking for

Comment: I'm interested in the times for intramolecular proton exchange in small molecules. I understand what you are saying regarding tautomerization being an equilibrium reaction

Comment: You could use standard  perturbation (relaxation) methods such as (small) temperature or pressure jump to study such reactions, for example $\ce{H2O<=>H^+ + OH^-}$ Searching for the technique may be a way to find data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a database, and I don't know about how small molecules you are looking for, I found that article on Jacs [Kinetics and thermodynamics of keto-enol tautomerism of simple carbonyl compounds: an approach based on a kinetic study of halogenation at low halogen concentrations](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00408a020?journalCode=jacsat)

If you can access the file it will be better for you, if not I let you some matrix of values. I hope it can help ! I give you them in the same the order of the publication.

I added some other publication at the end.

---

[image: tautomerism constant]

---

[image: Tautomerism bis]

---

[image: tautomerism ter]

---

**Links**

[Tautomerization of 2-Acetylcyclohexanone. 1. Characterization of Keto−Enol/Enolate Equilibria and Reaction Rates in Water](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo026629x?journalCode=joceah)

[Kinetic studies of keto-enol and other tautomeric
equilibria by flash photolysis](https://is.muni.cz/el/1431/podzim2009/IC036/Kinetic_studies_of_keto.pdf) (a lot of constants in this one)